# Async CTP - Ambient CancellationToken and IProgress

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-ctp, .net-4.5

Bearing in mind the Async CTP promotes implicit scheduling via an ambient `SynchronizationContext`, is there any reason why I should not make my `CancellationToken` and `IProgress` ambient too?

I'm currently passing these through methods, much like I was passing a `TaskScheduler` around for explicit scheduling. However, seeing as the scheduler is now supposed to be ambient, mightn't I follow the same rule for the other pieces of the puzzle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CancellationToken` is a more probable candidate for this than `IProgress<T>`. With `IProgress<T>`, you often have a different `T` at different levels (higher-level `async` methods combine the progress notifications of their lower-level `await` calls). With `CancellationToken`, the same token is almost always passed down to the lower-level `async` methods (assuming they support cancellation). `CancellationToken` does support some really advanced combinators, but they're hardly ever used.

The primary disadvantage is that you'd be departing from the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern. You'd have to keep in mind that any Microsoft or 3rd-party code would take an explicit `CancellationToken` - sp you'd have to explicitly pull it out of your ambient context in your lowest-level `async` methods. Also, programmers maintaining your code base later are likely to expect TAP.

There's also a challenge when you consider implementation. You'd want the implicit `CancellationToken` to follow the invocations of `async` methods, even if they change thread contexts. I mean, consider this: method `A` calls `ConfigureAwait(false)` before awaiting the result of method `B`. You can't use a simple thread-local static property, because you need to follow the async execution context from one thread to another.

I seem to recall reading about a way to do this (possibly using the [`CallContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.callcontext.aspx) class?), but as soon as you do it your performance tanks (the execution context migration code is highly optimized for the default scenario).

Comment: "I seem to recall reading about a way to do this (possibly using the CallContext class?)..."  Yes, the current internal builds of .NET 4.5 have support for this, but this wasn't in the version released at //BUILD.